# How do I instantiate a dynamic, empty array and add its first element?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to instantiate an empty array, where I'll be adding elements. For some reason, my script is throwing an error on simply calling `Ubound` on the empty array. I can't figure out how to instantiate an empty array... Here's what I've got:

```
Dim data_dates 
data_dates = Array("6/24/2019", "7/1/2019", "7/8/2019", "7/15/2019", "7/22/2019", "7/29/2019", "8/5/2019", "8/12/2019", "8/19/2019", "8/26/2019", "9/2/2019")
Dim site_dates

For date_iter = 1 To UBound(data_dates)
    If start_date <= data_dates(date_iter) And last_date <= data_dates(date_iter) Then
        MsgBox UBound(site_dates) '- LBound(site_dates) + 1
        site_dates(UBound(site_dates) + 1) = data_dates(date_iter)
    End If
Next date_iter
```

So that MsgBox line is throwing an error. Is it normal for Ubound to throw an error on an empty array? If so, how do I add the first element to an empty array?

Comment: "[Declaring arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays#declare-a-dynamic-array)" on MSDN has a section on Dynamic Arrays

Comment: Are you using Option base 1? Else your loop will miss the first element

Comment: * Is it normal for Ubound to throw an error on an empty array?*  `site_dates` is not an empty array; it is an uninitialized variable (empty variant), so yes, errors are normal.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim site_dates
```

This variable is an implicit `Variant`. While a `Variant` can very well hold an array, it initializes to `Variant/Empty`, which isn't an array - that's why `UBound(site_dates)` is throwing an error: you're trying to get the upper bound of a `Variant/Empty`, and VBA doesn't know what to do with that.

This declares a dynamic array of `Variant` items:

```
Dim site_dates()
```

That said, in general you should avoid resizing arrays (a loop with `ReDim Preserve theArray(UBound(theArray) + 1)` is copying the entire array at every iteration just to add a single item - the penalty gets more apparent with more items): if you don't know how many elements you're going to need, it's usually a better idea to use a `Collection` and `Add` items as you go. If you do know how many elements you're going to need, then explicitly size the array accordingly, at the declaration site:

```
Dim site_dates(1 To 10)
```

Note that `Dim` statements aren't executable, so you can't use a variable. Use the `ReDim` statement to do this:

```
ReDim site_dates(1 To datesCount)
```

`ReDim` acts as a declarative statement, so you don't need a prior `Dim`, even with `Option Explicit` specified.

In this case you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to get the number of dates matching the criteria and size the array before you start iterating the values.

Comment: Ah thanks, I had done `Dim site_dates() As Array` which wasn't working. As far as resizing the array, for `site_dates`, I won't know the size so I'll have to dynamically resize it. Luckily, it will never have more than 11 elements so I'm not too worried about performance.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Referring to *"... so you don't need a prior Dim"* - it might be worth to cite help at [MS `ReDim` Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement): 
*If another variable with the same name is created **later, even in a wider scope**, 
 `ReDim` will refer to the **later** variable and won't necessarily cause a compilation error, even if `Option Explicit` is in effect. To avoid such conflicts, `ReDim` should **not** be used as a **declarative statement**, but simply for redimensioning arrays.*

Answer (score 1):

One way to start the growth process:

```
Sub InTheBeginning()
    Dim site_dates() As Date, msg As String
    ReDim site_dates(1)

    For i = 1 To 10
        ReDim site_dates(1 To UBound(site_dates) + 1)
    Next i


    msg = LBound(site_dates) & vbCrLf & UBound(site_dates)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First to check that you are using Option base 1 because start your loops with 1??

If you have a setup where you know the max possible site_dates from your data_dates, you can ReDim the site_dates at the beginning (before the loop)to have the same bounds as data-dates.

Keep a track of the number of qualifying items written in a counter in the 'If logic' loop.
Then at the end, you can Redim Preserve down to the amount generated:

`ReDim Preserve site_dates(1 to qualifyingCounter)`

Alternatively, with no worry about performance you can consider the easiest for me:

Reference mscorlib and use an ArrayList

```
Dim data_dates
data_dates = Array("6/24/2019", "7/1/2019", "7/8/2019", "7/15/2019", "7/22/2019", "7/29/2019", "8/5/2019", "8/12/2019", "8/19/2019", "8/26/2019", "9/2/2019")

Dim siteDate_ArrayList As New ArrayList

Dim date_iter As Long
For date_iter = 0 To UBound(data_dates)
    If date_iter Mod 2 = 0 Then 'I changed this logic just for my test
        siteDate_ArrayList.Add data_dates(date_iter)
    End If
Next date_iter

Dim site_dates As Variant
'Please note that array resultant from ToArray on an empty ArrayList will have a Ubound of -1
site_dates = siteDate_ArrayList.ToArray
```

EDIT:
To refernce, go to Tools --> References and look down alphabetically for mscorlib.dll. Then check it.

[image]

Comment: How do I reference mscorlib? I've tried adding `Set clr = New mscoree.CorRuntimeHost` to the top of my script and elsewhere with no luck. Can't find any examples online that show where it's set